# what difference NSFetchRequest and NSFetchRequest<ResultType>

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm newb in swift from last month. :)
Today, I connect my basic NoteApp and CoreData instead Dummy with Array.
Some question About requesting

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Memo> = Memo.fetchRequest()
```

this is first code to request,

```
let request: NSFetchRequest = Memo.fetchRequest()
```

this is another code to request.

both code has no error and same result on simulator.

I think, my CoreData has just one Entity with 'Memo' this is why I can't find difference.

If my CoreData has bigger like more attribute or more Entity, it has some difference on these?

Comment: It's not on my case but sometimes will be problem. I'll remember this. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.

The compiler can infer the generic type so in this case the annotations `NSFetchRequest<Memo>` and `NSFetchRequest` are equal.

There is even a third form

```
let request = Memo.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest
```

Comment: It just type annotation! Thank you. :)